# Get handle of the MainWindow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, window-handles

I just created an empty WPF app in VS 2015.

It has

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var mainWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    }
}
```

But `mainWindowHandle`  is `0` always.

Is it OK? Should it be `> 0` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your window is not shown yet. So the actual window has not been created yet. Try examining this handle in `Activated` or `Loaded` event.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var mainWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! that's exactly whats i was looking for :)